# Getting Amazon EMR to use S3 for input and output

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr, mapr

How would I get Amazon EMR (0.20.205 MapR) to use S3 buckets for input and output?

I tried adding the following to the core configuration xml file (through bootstrap actions):

```
<property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>s3n://</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>dfs.name.default</name>
        <value>s3n://</value>
</property>
```

But I always get something like:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not resolve path:
>   s3n://some_out_bucket/out     at
>   com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.lookupClient(MapRFileSystem.java:219)  at
>   com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.delete(MapRFileSystem.java:385)    at
>   cc.mrlda.ParseCorpus.run(ParseCorpus.java:192)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)     at
>   cc.mrlda.ParseCorpus.main(ParseCorpus.java:675)   ... 10 more

Hadoop newbie here. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to the configuration steps described in the question above, I have modified the code:

`FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(outputPath), new JobConf(SomeClass.class));` where `outputPath` points to a resource on S3 e.g. `s3n://some_bucket`

Using `URI.create`, I am now able to access files directly from S3.